# Get Title of selected tab

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, title, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way of getting the value of the title of the page from a Google Extension?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At first you should declare the `tabs` API permission in your [`manifest.json`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html):

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "permissions": ["tabs"],
  ...
}
```

Then you will be able to use the tabs API, you are looking for the [`chrome.tabs.getSelected(windowId, callback)`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-getSelected) method.

To get the selected tab of the current window, you can simply pass `null` as the `windowId`.

This method will execute the callback function passing a [Tab](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#type-Tab) object as its first argument, where you can simply get the `title` property:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) { // null defaults to current window
  var title = tab.title;
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the above method mentioned by CMS is deprecated since Chrome 33.

You don't really need to specify the `tabs` permission in your manifest file since what you're doing here isn't some advanced action. You can perform most of the `tabs` actions without specifying the permission; only for some certain methods will you need to.

The new way of querying the currently selected tab is by the following code:

```
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true }, function (tab) {
  // do some stuff here
});
```

This will give you the selected tabs in **all windows**, if you have multiple windows open. If you want to get only the selected tab in the **current window**, use the following:

```
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tab) {
  // do some other fanciful stuff here
});
```

For more details, refer to https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query

Comment: **Wrong!** `"tabs"` permission is needed for `title` attribute. Depending on the situation though, [`"activeTab"` permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) may be sufficient.